# llamar a un controlador en Sprong boot

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

espero puedan ayudarme, tengo un problema, estoy inetentando actualizar los registros de un usuario, cuando el usaurio da en editar superfil se le muestra una pantalla con los campos que muede modificar, estos campos se llenan automaticamente con los datos actuales del usaurio. El usaurio al realizar los cambios en y dar la opcón de actualiar, se muestra un modal de confirmación, al aceptar se toma la infromación del usario que cambio y se deben actualizar en la DB. Mi problema radica en este último paso. No sé cómo puedo mandar a llamar a mi controlador el cual se encarga de actualizar los datos, desde la vista.

Estoy utilizando thymeleaf.

Anexo captura de pantalla de mi controlador y del fragmento del modal (footer), donde deseo mandar a llamar a mi controlador.

Contolador

```
@GetMapping(value = "/actualizarDatosInternos/{id}")
public String actualizarUsuarioInterno(WebRequest request, @RequestParam("id") final String id,
        @ModelAttribute Usuario user) {
    
       log.debug("Entre a actualizarusuarioInterno");

        Usuario userActualizado = usuarioService.obtenerUsuarioPorId(id);
        log.debug("userActualizado" + userActualizado);
        
        usuarioService.editarUsuarioLau(userActualizado);
        
        
        log.debug("Fin del controlador");
        return "redirect:/usuarios";
      

}
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Aceptar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que se actualize la data tienes que mandar por medio de un formluarion ()

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
   <form method="POST" action="/updateUser">
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Aceptar" />
   </form>
</div>
```